# How to set css class 'active' by using C#?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I would like to add a css class to `<li class=''></li>` item. Can you help?

```
public static string IsMenuActive(Blms.Model.MenuItem menuItem)
{
        string result = "";

        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["Url"].ToLower().IndexOf(GetMenuLink(menuItem).ToLower()) >= 0)
            result = "active";

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result)) {
            foreach (var child in menuItem.Children)
            {
                if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["Url"].ToLower().IndexOf(GetMenuLink(child).ToLower()) >= 0)
                {
                    result = "active";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

HTML side:

```
 <li class="@Blms.Web.Core.MenuUtilities.GetMenuLiClass(menuItem) @Blms.Web.Core.MenuUtilities.IsMenuActive(menuItem)">
```

Comment: @MattHouser: it selects all parent item. it must select only one.

Comment: I know it's not the question but I would suggest using Jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a custom htmlhelper to solve this problem. It will result in a cleaner view.

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/writing-custom-html-helpers-for-asp.net-mvc/